# Redirect to Razor Page from MVC View in .NET Core

Tags: .net, asp.net-core, razor-pages

I have a simple view with an `<a>` link. I want to redirect after clicking it to Razor Page with model. I did `asp-page="/mypage"` but it just changes the url to /SiteFromWhichIRedirect/mypage but nothing more. The page I'm currently on (the one with `<a>` tag) just refreshes.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

When click `<a>`,it will create a Get Request.And if you want to pass data,you need to add attribute like asp-route-xxx.For example,you want to pass Id and Name. link need to be like:

```
<a asp-page="Create" asp-route-id="1" asp-route-name="name1">Create</a>
```

If you want to go to razor page handler you can use `asp-page-handler`:

```
<a asp-page-handler="Create" asp-route-id="1" asp-route-name="name1">Create</a>
```

Here is a demo:

Model:

```
public class Student
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }

    }
```

cshtml.cs:

```
public class IndexModel : PageModel
    {
        public IActionResult OnGet()
        {
            return Page();
        }
        public IActionResult OnGetCreate(Student s) {
            return Page();
        }
    }
```

cshtml:

```
<a asp-page-handler="Create" asp-route-id="1" asp-route-name="name1">Create</a>
```

result:
[image]